Why does molar conductivity of strong electrolyte increases on decreasing the concentration i.e. by doing dilution

My teacher first told me that strong electrolytes form more ions
cause they dissociate completely so if we increase the concentration then more ions will be formed and hence conductivity will be more.


But on the other hand when he explained molar conductivity of strong electrolyte, he said that here conductivity will increase if concentration decreases that is when you do dilution.

So aren't both of these points are contradictory!!!!....how will molar conductivity increase if concentration will decrease for a strong electrolyte.

Your teacher's point (1) and (2) are not contradictory but a consequence of mathematics and chemical properties of ions and the solvent. You are right, the more the ions, the more conductivity to an extent. However, when you try to normalize (=divide) the observed conductivity with corresponding molar concentration, the resulting number, called the molar conductivity, is not a constant. Instead this calculated number decreases. It would have been a constant, as it should be, if conductivity only reflected the number of charge carries. It does not. What you must seek now is the chemical explanation which are readily provided in textbooks, as to why molar conductivity is decreasing with concentration. Basically As the population of the ion increases, the ions are no longer independent charge carriers, the ions start to get influenced by the surroundings.
In short, there is no short-cut to reading a textbook on physical chemistry or visiting the college/school library. See Kohlrausch's law. On the web, you will find all types of explanations, and as a fresh student it will be difficult to assess who is right or wrong.
